# Add/remove Knockout observableArray nested elements

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm trying to add to/remove from a nested observableArray in KnockoutJS. I have an array several elements, each with an attribute object, type object and an attributeValue array which holds objects. So it's a nested array.

The allAttributes array is observableArray. Then I tried making the attributeValue array observable by making a new ViewModel (attributeValueViewModel) with attributeValues as ko.observableArray([]).

I made two Knockout functions (which don't work) and I'm trying to add/remove values to/from that array. The problem is that the array is nested so I have to access the attributeID through this.attribute.id. self.allAttributes[i].attributeValues[j] should be the object I'm adding/removing... where *i=attributeID and j=index of the attribute's value object*

Why aren't those functions working?

Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/M6Hqj/2/

Comment: cool story. now where is the question?

Comment: Haha sorry bro, the functions aren't working. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you're overwriting the observable function in your inner view model, e.g. when you assign `obj.attribute = item.attribute;`, you're overwriting your initial assignment of `self.attribute = ko.observable(data.attribute);`. Instead assign the value through the observable, like so:

```
obj.attribute(item.attribute); //instead of obj.attribute = item.attribute;
```

This will also make your `self.addAttributeValue()` function call work since the array is now observable.

Next, in your `self.removeAttributeValue()` function, the `this` call actually refers to the specific record *inside* your `attributeValues` array, therefore, when you do `this.attributeValues.splice()`, it can't find your `attributeValues` object property. So, shift the function into the `attributeValueViewModel` object and use `self` instead of `this`, like so:

```
//This is inside function attributeValueViewModel(data)
self.removeAttributeValue = function() {
    alert(JSON.stringify(this));
    self.attributeValues.splice(this.id, 1);
}
```

To call it, just change your data-bind code to use `$parent` instead of `$root`, like so:

```
<button data-bind="click: $parent.removeAttributeValue">REMOVE</button>
```

Something like this fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/UMB79/

(Note that with these changes you still have to modify your logic to correctly add/remove elements, 'cause it's still buggy)